# How do you use DefaultTreeNode(nodeType, data, parentNode)?

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

How do you use DefaultTreeNode(nodeType, data, parentNode)?

Basically if I do this:

```
treeChild = new DefaultTreeNode("action", data, treeParent);
```

My tree view is blank.

If I use this instead:

```
treeChild = new DefaultTreeNode(data, treeParent);
```

Then my tree view displays.

Is DefaultTreeNode(nodeType, data, parentNode) broken?

Comment: Check DocumentsController.java in http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/treeTable.jsf

Comment: Note that it would have worked with `treeChild = new DefaultTreeNode("default", data, treeParent);`. If you're not using "default", then you have to define `<p:treeNode nodeType="action">` where "action" is the type passed to DefaultTreeNode 3-parameters constructor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe I found the solution.  Here it is:

1 - In tree.xhtml I had to include a **tree** element with a **treeNode** element for each node type.

```
<p:tree id="treeSingle" 
    value="#{treeBean.root}" 
    var="node"
    selectionMode="single"
    selection="#{treeBean.selectedNode}"
    dynamic="true"
    style="width:98%;height:100%;">
    <p:treeNode type="#{treeBean.LEAF_TYPE}">
       <h:outputText value="#{node}" />
    </p:treeNode>
    <p:treeNode type="#{treeBean.ACTION_TYPE}">
       <h:outputText value="#{node}" />
    </p:treeNode>
    <p:treeNode type="#{treeBean.VALUE_TYPE}">
       <h:outputText value="#{node}" />
    </p:treeNode>
</p:tree>
```

2 - Then in tree.xhtml I also had to define the menus for each node type like this:

```
<p:contextMenu for="treeSingle" nodeType="#{treeBean.LEAF_TYPE}">
    <p:menuitem value="View" actionListener="#{treeBean.displaySelectedSingle}" icon="ui-icon-search" update=":infoMessages"/>
    <p:menuitem value="Delete" update="treeSingle" actionListener="#{treeBean.deleteNode}" icon="ui-icon-close"/>
</p:contextMenu>
<p:contextMenu for="treeSingle" nodeType="#{treeBean.ACTION_TYPE}">
    <p:menuitem value="Execute" actionListener="#{treeBean.execute}" update=":infoMessages"/>
</p:contextMenu>
<p:contextMenu for="treeSingle" nodeType="#{treeBean.VALUE_TYPE}">
    <p:menuitem value="Edit" actionListener="#{treeBean.edit}" icon="ui-icon-edit" update=":infoMessages"/>
    <p:menuitem value="Delete" update="treeSingle" actionListener="#{treeBean.deleteNode}" icon="ui-icon-close"/>
</p:contextMenu>
```

3 - Then in my TreeBean, I exposed the following properties like this:

```
private static final String LEAF_TYPE  = "leaf";
private static final String ACTION_TYPE = "action";
private static final String VALUE_TYPE = "value";

public String getLEAF_TYPE(){
    return LEAF_TYPE;
}
public String getACTION_TYPE(){
    return ACTION_TYPE;
}
public String getVALUE_TYPE(){
    return VALUE_TYPE;
}
```

4 - And finally in TreeBean, I created the nodes like this:

```
TreeNode node = new DefaultTreeNode(ACTION_TYPE, data, parentNode); 
TreeNode node = new DefaultTreeNode(LEAF_TYPE, data, parentNode); 
TreeNode node = new DefaultTreeNode(VALUE_TYPE, data, parentNode);
```